# Generated de-normalised View table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have a system that makes use of a database View, which takes data from a few reference tables (lookups) and then does a lot of pivoting and complex work on a hierarchy table of (pretty much fixed and static) locations, returning a view view of data to the application.

This view is getting slow, as new requirements are added.

A solution that may be an option would be to create a normal table, and select from the view, into this table, and let the application use that highly indexed and fast table for it's querying.

Issue is, I guess, if the underlying tables change, the new table will show old results. But the data that drives this table changes very infrequently. And if it does - a business/technical process could be made that means an 'Update the Table' procedure is run to refresh this data. Or even an update/insert trigger on the primary driving table?

Is this practice advised/ill-advised? And are there ways of making it safer?

Comment: You can think of it as caching. I update/refresh a table/cache with the result of a complex query every few minutes, so users see data that is few minutes old. It may be acceptable for you. Also, have a look at [indexed views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms191432.aspx). But, they have rather [strict limitations](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/).

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov - That's helpful. I wanted to use Indexed Views, but as I need to do a Pivot within the view, or within a function used by the view, I'm breaching the limitations. My only option seems to be the cached table.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to optimise the underlying queries.

In SSMS run the slow query and include the actual execution plan (Ctrl + M), this will give you a graphical representation of how the query is being executed against your database.
Another helpful tool is to turn on IO statistics, this is usually the main bottleneck with queries, put this line at the top of your query window:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

1. Check if SQL recommends any missing indexes (displayed in green in the execution plan), as you say the data changes infrequently so it should be safe to add additional indexes if needed.
2. In the execution plan you can hover your mouse over any element for more information, check the value for estimated rows vs actual rows returned, if this varies greatly update the statistics for the tables, this can help the query optimiser find the best execution plan.
   To do this for all tables in a database:

   USE [Database_Name]

   GO

   exec sp_updatestats

Still no luck in optimising the view / query?

Be careful with update triggers as if the schema changes on the view/table (say you add a new column to the source table) the new column will not be inserted into your 'optimised' table unless you update the trigger.

If it is not a business requirement to report on real time data there is not too much harm in having a separate optimized table for reporting (Much like a DataMart), just use a SQL Agent job to refresh it nightly during non-peak hours. 
There are a few cons to this approach though:

- More storage space / duplicated data
- More complex database
- Additional workload during the refresh
- Decreased cache hits